# Show different image in dataGridview from sql server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, vb.net

I have a table in sql server that have column have images, and I retrieve the image by adding image column in `Gridview` if the user click on image column, the application go to database and check if that row have data in image column will show the picture in new form, every thing is perfect 
and this is the code :

this id how I fill the `Gridview`:

```
Sub FillGridd()
    Dim cbb As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn() With {.HeaderText = "currency"}
    cbb.Items.Add("shekel")
    cbb.Items.Add("dinar")
    cbb.Items.Add("dollar")
    cbb.Items.Add("euro")
    cbb.Items.Add("yuan")
    cbb.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
    'Delete Button
    Dim btnDelete As New DataGridViewButtonColumn()
    btnDelete.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
    'Image Button
    Dim btnImage As New DataGridViewButtonColumn()
    btnDelete.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup

    Dim column = New CalendarColumn() With {.HeaderText = "Date"}
    column.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"
    column.DataPropertyName = "Date"

    MetroGrid2.Columns.Insert(0, btnDelete)
    MetroGrid2.Columns.Add("", "المبلغ المرسل")
    MetroGrid2.Columns.Add(cbb)
    MetroGrid2.Columns.Add("", "Commission")
    MetroGrid2.Columns.Add("", "receiver name")
    MetroGrid2.Columns.Add("", "receiver phone")
    MetroGrid2.Columns.Add("", "Recipient country")
    MetroGrid2.Columns.Add("", "sender's name")
    MetroGrid2.Columns.Add("", "sender's phone")
    MetroGrid2.Columns.Add("", "the recipient company")
    'MetroGrid2.Columns.Add("", "Date")
    MetroGrid2.Columns.Add(column)
    MetroGrid2.Columns.Add(btnImage)
    MetroGrid2.Columns.Add("", "Notes")
    MetroGrid2.Columns.Add("", "ID")
    MetroGrid2.Columns(13).Visible = False


    Const sqlstring As String = "SELECT * FROM money_sent WHERE date >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE()) ORDER BY Date DESC"

    If SQL.conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        SQL.conn.Close()
    End If
    SQL.conn.Open()
    Dim adt As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlstring, SQL.conn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    adt.Fill(dt)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        MetroGrid2.Rows.Add()
        MetroGrid2.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(1)
        Dim cell As DataGridViewComboBoxCell = DirectCast(MetroGrid2.Rows(i).Cells(2), DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
        cell.Value = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(2)
        MetroGrid2.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(3)
        MetroGrid2.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(4)
        'DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value = "DELETE"
        MetroGrid2.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(5)
        MetroGrid2.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(6)
        MetroGrid2.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(7)
        MetroGrid2.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(8)
        MetroGrid2.Rows(i).Cells(9).Value = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(9)
        MetroGrid2.Rows(i).Cells(10).Value = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(10)
        MetroGrid2.Rows(i).Cells(12).Value = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(12)
        MetroGrid2.Rows(i).Cells(13).Value = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(0)
    Next
    SQL.conn.Close()

    'MetroGrid2.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.SingleHorizontal
    MetroGrid2.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.Single
    Me.MetroGrid2.GridColor = Color.WhiteSmoke
End Sub
```

this is how i add clickable image in `Gridview`:

```
     Private Sub MetroGrid2_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles MetroGrid2.CellContentClick
    id = MetroGrid2.SelectedRows(0).Cells(13).Value
    If e.ColumnIndex = 11 Then
            Dim dr As SqlDataReader
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand
            Dim stream As New MemoryStream()
            Dim query As String
            query = "select * from money_sent where id='" & id & "'"

            If SQL.conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                SQL.conn.Close()
            End If
            SQL.conn.Open()
            cmd = New SqlCommand(query, SQL.conn)
            'dr = Cmd.ExecuteReader
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            While dr.Read
                If dr("idpicture").ToString() <> "" Then
                    Dim image As [Byte]() = DirectCast(dr("idpicture"), [Byte]())
                    stream.Write(image, 0, image.Length)
                    Dim bitmap As New Bitmap(stream)
                    'Form3.PictureBox1.Image = bitmap
                    Dim frm As New Form3
                    frm.PictureBox1.Image = bitmap
                    frm.id = id
                    frm.sname = MetroGrid2.SelectedRows(0).Cells(7).Value
                    frm.ShowDialog()
                Else
                    noimage = "no"
                End If
            End While
            SQL.conn.Close()

            If noimage = "no" Then
                If MessageBox.Show("there is no image for this record do you want add image ?", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = DialogResult.Yes Then
                    UpdateImage()
                End If
            End If
        End If
End Sub
```

This is All the code, now what i want is how to show different image in the `Gridview` Image column for the row that have picture in database, so the user can distinguish the row that have picture from the one that no picture in it.

This is How the Image column in the `Gridview`:
[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to show some standard image when there is no image associated with a record?  Wouldnt you need 2 such images, 1 for "yes click to see it" and one for "no image to click to"?

Comment: Yes, i already done the yes "yes click to see it and one for no image to click to " what i want to show default image when no image in the record and another image when there is image in the record, actually yes this what i need like you said

Comment: Make one the NO one the NullValue property for the DefaultCellStyle or use the Image property of the Image column.  Note: there are easier ways to populate a DGV even when one column is a custom one

Comment: Show me please, because this way take time to show all data and the program turn to black screen the it show the data, and make it an answer to vote for you thank you.